# When a user access a directory directly, Is a GET request sent by default?

Tags: php, http-post

I have a page with this code:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'GET') {
    header('HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed');
    exit(); }
```

If I access it with a form in GET method, it works, and doesn't exit, which is ok.
But when I try to access this file directly, I would expect the file to perform the exit -
unless, a GET request is sent automatically whenever one access a file, even when not through a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> unless, a GET request is sent automatically whenever one access a file, even when not through a form?

It is.

When you follow a link or type a URL into the address bar, you are getting a resource (you aren't asking for just metadata (HEAD), or sending any kind of data (PUT, POST), or deleting something (DELETE)) so you use GET.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifically issue a `POST`, `PUT`, `HEAD`, etc. request then it is `GET`.  If you click a link in a page or use the URL bar in the browser it is `GET`.